# How to post a comment only for one article? php

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I post a comment for article the comment post every articles on my application.
How can I post comment only for one article?

If you have any advice or thought I really appliciate.
Thank you!

```
<!-- Comments Form -->
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $users = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?');
    $users->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
    $user = $users->fetch();
}

if(isset($_POST['create_comment'])){
    $comment_post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    
    $comment = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO comments SET comment_user_id=?, comment_post_id=?, comment_contents=?, created_time=NOW()');
    $comment->execute(array(
        
        $user['user_id'],
        $comment_post_id['comment_post_id'],
        $_POST['comment_contents']
        ));
        
    header('Location: post.php');
    exit();
}
?>
            <div class="well">
                <form action="" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Comment">Your Comment</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="comment_contents"></textarea>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="create_comment" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr>

<!-- Comment -->
<?php 
$comments = $db->query('SELECT u.user_name, c.*, p.* FROM users u, comments c, posts p WHERE u.user_id=c.comment_user_id AND p.post_id=c.comment_post_id ORDER BY c.created_time DESC');
?>
<!-- Comment Preview -->
<h5>Comments</h5>
<hr>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <?php $comment['post_id']; ?>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['comment_contents'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['user_name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>  |  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['created_time'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>
    <?php if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $comment['comment_user_id']): ?>
    <a href="delete_comment.php?delete_comment_id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['comment_id']); ?>">Delete comment</a> 
    <?php endif; ?>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment Table
[image]

Post Table
[image]

User Table
[image]

Comment: Post = article ?

Comment: The PHP code expects that the posted comment form will include a "post_id" variable, but the HTML you've shown for your form doesn't include any such data - for example, you might expect it should be there in a hidden field, pre-populated with the ID of the post the form is attached to. Or is it part of the URL as a query string parameter? It isn't clear, from what you've posted.

Comment: So what is _"the comment post every articles on my application"_ actually supposed to mean? Do you get a new record inserted into your comments table, as many times as you have posts? I rather doubt that, there isn't any loop visible in the code you have shown, that could cause that. So what does it mean then? Does the `comment_post_id` column get filled with a post ID at all - or is it mabye set to blank/null? And that makes your later logic to _show_ the comments related to the individual posts, trip up?

Comment: @ADyson it doesn't necessarily expect it from the form _fields_ though - `$_REQUEST['post_id']` could be accessing a GET parameter that was present in the form action. (Which is set to `""` here, so the page the form is one would have to have been requested with that GET parameter set already.)

Comment: @CBroe you're right, we don't know that for sure. It's unclear in the question, I guess.  I've amended my comment. But also I noticed that the resulting variable is then included in the SQL parameters as if it's an array (i.e. `$comment_post_id['comment_post_id']`), which is unlikely to be the case. So an extra issue there, too.